# Making a groupbox button win32 C++

Tags: c++, winapi

i have a button that is a rectangle how would i put words in it i want to make so ican click the word and it starts the progrma i know ShellExecute the style is BS_GROUPBOX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one program you want to start, you need a button per program you want to start.

To start you external progrma, in the button parent window, you need to process the [`WM_COMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647591(VS.85).aspx) message with the [`BN_CLICKED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761825(VS.85).aspx) notification.

To set the text of the button, you need to send [`WM_SETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632644(VS.85).aspx) message to the button with the text you want shown.

Btw, `BS_GROUPBOX` is used for creating the rectangle around radio buttons. This style is not going to work for your scenario.

If you want an alternative to using multiple Button controls, you can use a [Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760435(VS.85).aspx). In fact, it seems to me that a toolbar would be a better control for you. You can read more about [creating a toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760446(VS.85).aspx#Creating_Toolbars).